# Adam's physical maturity when created

Tags: creation, age, adam

According to Jewish tradition, what was Adam's level of physical maturity (apparent age) when he was created? Was he a baby or an adult?

Comment: I can't find a source now, but since G-d gave Adam Eve to be his wife and partner, and since they kicked out of Eden only few hours after Adam was created, that means Adam was created an adult man.

Comment: this website refers to an opinion that he was 20 years old http://www.jewishpress.com/indepth/interviews-and-profiles/modern-science-is-discovering-what-the-torah-said-thousands-of-years-ago-an-interview-with-rabbi-yosef-bitton/2013/09/17/0/?print but gives no source

Comment: I thought we'd had this question before but I can't find it.

Comment: Check Cholin 60a "דאמר ריב''ל כל מעשה בראשית בקומתן נבראו בדעתן נבראו בצביונם נבראו "

Comment: [Rabbi Micha Berger](/users/1570/micha-berger) [says](http://www.torah.org/linkedlists/torah-forum/fu/0682.html) there's a _machklokes_ in a _mishna_, but I don't know where that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bereishit_Rabbah.14.7](http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.14.7)

> ... אמר רבי יוחנן: אדם וחוה כבני עשרים שנה נבראו ...
>
> Rabbi Yohanan said Adam and Eve were created as **20 year olds**

See [Did Adam and Eve have bellybuttons, fingerprints or ridge over lip?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37884/5120)

[Talmud - Mas. Rosh HaShana 11a](http://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Chullin.pdf#page=195)

> This is to be explained in accordance with the dictum  of R. Joshua b. Levi; for R. Joshua b. Levi said: All creatures of the creation were brought into being with their full stature, their full capacities, and their full beauty, as it says, And  the heaven and the earth were finished, and all the host of them [zeba'am]. Read not zeba'am, but zibyonam [their beauty].

[Talmud - Mas. Chullin 60a](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Rosh_HaShanah.pdf#page=26)

> Rab Judah further said: The bullock which Adam  sacrificed had fully developed horns before it had hoofs,  as it is said: ‘And it shall please the Lord better than a bullock that hath horns and hoofs’; the verse first says: ‘that hath horns’ and then ‘hoofs’. This supports  R. Joshua b. Levi, who said: All the animals of  the creation were created in their full-grown  stature, with their consent, and according to the shape of their  own choice, for it is written: And the heaven and the earth were finished, and all the host of them 7  read not zeba'am 8  but zibyonam. 9

---

@msh210 above brings this [link](http://www.torah.org/linkedlists/torah-forum/fu/0682.html)

That says

> Actually, there are two opinions in the mishnah, whether Adam was created as
> a baby, or at an apparent age of 20.

I also (@msh210) did not yet find what he is referring to

---

As the author of the linked material... I was referring to R' Eliezer's position (despite it being in the gemara, not a mishnah, it is introduced with a "tanya"). The quote from RH 11a above is where R Yehoshua ben Levi is quoted as support to R' Yehoshua's opinion. The other side of that dispute is R' Eliezer, who says the world was created in Tishrei, with everything in its infancy. He doesn't mention Adam as an example, but he does consistently say everything was in its infancy. And R Yehoshua ben Levi is described as proof of R' Yehoshua over R' Eliezer.