# What is the need for angels?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, creation, malach-angel

Why did G-d create angels to assign them specific tasks ([Bava Metzia 86b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=86b&format=text))? Since G-d is omnipotent, what is the need for angels -- why doesn't He perform these tasks directly?

Comment: First one would have to define exactly what angels are and what their exact function is before one can really ask why God made them.

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi Ahron Lopiansky described angels as being for our benefit. The parable he used was as follows; when a layperson looks at a car, they have no idea how it runs, it is just a car. However when they are able to separate the different parts of the car, they can begin to fathom how the car functions.

Per this, angels exist to help us understand creation and God's interaction with it. They are like different parts of a car that are made distinct from one another so we can understand how the car works. They are sent on specific tasks so that we can have documented exposure to them, which in turn fulfills their purpose.

Comment: When do we have documented exposure to angels?

Comment: @user6618 Explicitly in-verse off the top of my head, Genesis, Numbers, Judges, Kings, Isaiah, Ezekiel, Daniel. Also a ton of Aggadic works illustrate the use of angels in a homiletic, metaphoric sense, to help us understand.

Comment: Isn't that more of an exception than a rule? Usually we don't see angels, and if the purpose of them was for us to have documented exposure to them, wouldn't we see them often? @babyseal

Comment: @user6618 no because understanding how creation works is non essential to keeping the mitzvot.

Comment: You're saying the _purpose_ of angels is for us to have exposure to them (so we can understand G-d). So if that's their _purpose_, we should always get that exposure whenever they are performing an assigned task.

Comment: @user6618 we do, either in verse or in Midrash. And you can't understand God, only how he interacts with us.

Comment: @user6618 also this may not be clear, but Rav Lopiansky's core point was that without angels we wouldn't be able to understand the difference between wood and oxygen and fire and how they collaborate. So by virtue of the fact that science exists, we are reaping the benefits of the existence of angels.

Answer (score 1):

The Ramchal in Derech Hashem
states (as far as i understand) that the purpose of angels/spiritual forces is to give man the ability to make greater impacts and changes. 
That everything emanates from the infinite, and there is a gradual unfolding of the divine will starting with the most non physical of forces and eventually to more and more physical (ie. the constelations) ending in our physical world. It is possible for man to effect a spiritual force and then effect millions of physical ramifications from that one spiritual change. He notes that in order for the reward/punishment system to work, there has to be the negative forces that correspond.

ואולם רצה האדון, ברוך הוא, שיהיה דרך לאדם שיוכל להתפתח במקצת מקישורי הגופניות הזה ושלשלאותיו, ויגיעו לו עניינים שלא כמשפט הגופניות אלא כמשפט הרוחניות, ועל ידי זה תגיע לו השכלה והשגה ברוחניים וענייניהם, מה שהיה נעדר ממנו לפי מצבו הגשמי וגבוליו. וכן תעלה בידו יותר, העמדת המציאות כולם על המצב הטוב הנאות בהם, למעלה ולמטה בשורשים ובענפים. 
........
האדם יכול להשתמש במציאות שימוש רוחני
ז. והנה על היסוד הזה עומד המצא היכולת לאדם להשתמש בנמצאות בשימוש הרוחני וכמו שכתבתי למעלה, ולפעול פעולות גדולות וחזקות מה שאינו באפשרות השימוש הגשמי.

וזה כי הנה האדון, ברוך הוא, הכין סדרי המציאויות וכונניותיהם על זה הדרך, שכולם נקשרים זה בזה, וכולם תלויים בהשפעותיו יתברך שזכרנו, באופן שכשתימשך אחת מן ההשפעות על ידי הזכרת אחד משמותיו יתברך כמו שכתבתי, הנה תולד מזה התולדה עד סוף ההשתלשלות. כי הנה הוא יתברך שמו ימצא לקוראיו באותו השם כפי מה שסידר ורצה, ויאיר אותו האור, וישפיע אותה ההשפעה, שבה תלוי מציאות העניין ההוא המבוקש, עד סוף העניין שבגשמיות.

ואמנם עוד עניין אחד חוקק הבורא יתברך שמו על זה הדרך, והוא, כי הנה המלאכים כולם בכל מדרגותיהם, הנה נמסר בידם כוח לפעול פעולות מה שנמסרו להם, והנה אינם פועלים בתמידות, אלא כפי הסדר שהוסדר להנהגה הטבעית התמידית של העולם.

אמנם יש בכוחם שיכולים לפעול ממין הפעולה ההיא יותר ממה שפועלים בתמידות, וביותר כוח וחוזק שלא כסדר התמידי. ובזה הדרך יפעלו פעמים רבות במעשה הנסים והנפלאות, שיחודשו בעולם כפי רצונו יתברך בעת שירצה.

שימוש בשם האלוהים
ואמנם רצה האדון, ברוך הוא, ונתן כבוד לשמו, שכשיוזכר על המלאכים לפי הסדר שסידר, דהיינו על מלאכי פעולה אחת, השם שנתייחס לו יתברך על שם ההשפעה שבה נתלה העניין ההוא כולו, הנה יוכרח המלאך לפעול באותו הכוח היתר שנמסר בידו לאותה הפעולה, כפי מה שיכריחהו המזכיר את השם עליו.

ונמצאו בעניין הזה שני שורשים: 
האחד הוא הזכרת שמו יתברך, כמי שקורא אותו שיענהו, וימשיך על ידי זה ממנו השפעה, שבהמשכה יחודשו עניינים מה שיחודשו. 
והשני - הכריח את המלאכים על ידי שמו יתברך, שיפעלו מה שבידם לפעול יתר על הסדר התמידי.

ואמנם אין שום אחד מן העניינים האלה מוחלטים לכל רצונו של האדם, אלא מוגבלים בגבולים ובתנאים, ומשוערים עד היכן יגיע היכולת להשתמש בהם, ובאיזה דרך יצליחו. וכבר אפשר שתימנע התולדה ויעוכב הפועל, אפילו באותו השיעור עצמו שניתן להשתמש בו, כמו שתימנע תולדת השימוש הטבעי גם כן בגזירתו יתברך אם יגזור על זה.

ואולם לשורש האחד, שהוא הזכרת שמו יתברך להמשך ממנו ההשפעה, ודאי שיצטרך הקורבה אליו יתברך והדבקות בו. וכל מה שירבה העניין הזה, יצלח הדבר ביד העושה אותו, וכל מה שימעט - יתקשה עליו השגת התכלית. 
ולשורש השני אין תנאי זה מצטרך, אף על פי שלא יניח מהיותו עוזר לו אם ימצא. כי הנה אחרי שהושם בסגולת השמות האלה שיוכרחו המלאכים בהזכרתם, הנה שבו גם הם ככל הכלים הטבעיים, שיפעל בם המשתמש בם כפי רצונו, אם ישתמש מהם בדרך שימושם כראוי.

.......
ט. והנה על פי הדרך הזה, כמו שהמציא לאדם דרך להשיג בו הארה והשכלה ורוח הקודש שלא כדרך הטבע הגשמי, כן הוצרך שימצא לטוב הגדול הזה, ההפך, והוא שיוכל האדם להמשיך חושך ועכירות ורוח טומאה שלא כדרך הטבעי, והוא עניין טומאות הכישוף והדרישה של המתים, שהרחיקתנו התורה מהם.

Comment: Good source, but the question is kinda two-pronged. This addresses in part the need for angels, but not why God doesn't do things himself!

Comment: I believe that the reason is that for an infinite being to interact with a finite creation which is so unrelated to it, there needs to be progressively less and less spiritual entities.This process is called Hishtalshulus, with the constelations being 1 link. 4 rabbis went up to pardes and only Rabbi akiva remained, Rav yaakov meir Shachter explains that the angelic being they saw was so almost infinite that it was inconcievable that there was a being greater then it, only rabbi akiva said, if this is under god, how amazing must god be. The ramchal states this concept in derech hashem.

Comment: So I think the issue with that understanding, avner, is  that it implies that God needs angels to interact with this world, which is the core of the question.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to describe a reality. God *is* directly interacting with the world, *and he's doing so by himself*, from infinite to finite. And angels are simply puppet strings and links in a chain from infinite to finite? Perhaps your answer is that the premise of the question is flawed because it ascribes more sentience and autonomy to angels than there actually is?

Answer (score -1):

Even though God is omnipotent and does not have needed to rest, but he did so on the seventh day and made it holy. This suggests that although there is no direct need for angels to do His work, it does allow us to better understand how this work is arranged and split amongst various role players.

I particularly like the story about the angel of forgetfulness whose role allows the re-incarnated soul to not know of its past experience. But sometimes this angel also forgets, which explains why very rarely we get a "flash-back" from an experience we think we have never had.

Comment: If you can perhaps better source that last paragraph, perhaps you can answer [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40637/what-is-d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-vu) question as well. (No idea who downvoted or why).

Comment: -1: I don't understand the connenction between God 'resting' on the seventh day, which just means that He was done with creating the world, and the second sentence: "[angels] allow us to better understand how this work is arranged". God didn't stop creating the world in the middle of it and then allocate the rest of the jobs to angels, unless I'm missing a few pesukim in my chumash. But it would be awesome if you could source the story in the second paragraph- I've never heard it before

Comment: Unless of course you mean this angel, in which case I have heard a similar story: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lethe