# What is the occupation of the soul, Jewish and non-Jewish, in the months prior to birth?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, agada-stories-legends

After reading an interesting [scientific article concerning how mammals apparently dream prior to birth](https://www.studyfinds.org/mammals-dream-before-birth/), it reminded me of [Rabbi Simlai in Niddah 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.30b.18?lang=bi) discussing how each Jewish soul learns the entire Torah prior to its birth.

Are there other sources *within Torah literature* that discuss the occupation of the soul prior to its descent and birth into this world? Is there a differentiation between the *Jewish soul* and *other souls*? Does this even relate to the souls of all animals like the scientific observation suggests?

Comment: I have seen references that the Jewish soul studies Torah and forgets the learning upon birth. There is a reference that the dent above the lips and below the nose is caused by the touch of a malach upon birth., causing the forgetting of the infant. If that is the case, then even a nonJewish fetus would have learned something appropriate that is forgotten upon birth. However, I have no idea what that would be.

Comment: @sabbahillel Sounds the beginning of a good answer. Needs research...

Comment: @sabbahillel Just in the context of the link to the article which appeared in Science Magazine, it discusses all mammals. That’s a much broader scope than just humans. And the obvious question is, if it relates to all mammals, does this go beyond even that limitation to include all living things, everything with a soul?

Comment: I have been told that animals do not have the dent because they do not have a neshamah like a human being and would not have been taught what a human fetus has learned. Thus, they would not have the interaction with a malach that a human being does.

Comment: https://mishpacha.com/the-angels-gift/  discusses the learning in the womb in depth

Comment: According to this shiur https://www.maharitz.co.il?CategoryID=252&ArticleID=2135 it sounds like everyone learns some Torah in the womb. See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29673/what-is-the-source-for-the-tradition-that-the-philtrum-is-formed-by-an-angel-bef

Comment: R Simlai's prooftexts are self descriptions from Iyov. There is no reason to think he is talking about Jews in particular.

Comment: @MichaBerger Excellent observation. And what are the implications of that in terms of the relationship between the Jewish people and the other nations in terms of symbiosis?

Comment: @YaacovDeane I heard my Rav state many times that Tehillim 23 and 62 are talking about the soul in the womb. 23 talks about birth (valley of shadow of death), and 62 talk about being alone (because the parents are asleep). The soul is fully aware of everything going on throughout the whole birth process, which is why it is so important to speak and behave appropriately in front of the neshama of one's child, it has a huge effect